# Differentiability on an open interval leads to continuity on the closed interval

Tags: calculus

I am wondering if a function $f$ is differentiable on an open interval $(a,b)$, we can say that $f$ is continuous on the closed interval $[a,b]$?

Comment: How about $f $ which discontinuous at $a $ and continuous in $(a,b]$?

Comment: The answer is no (a good counterexample is below), and that's why the Mean Value Theorem requires both hypotheses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, $f(x) = x$ for $0 < x < 1$, $f(0) = f(1) = 8$.

Comment: Thnanks Quimey!

Answer (score 3):

Nope. For instance, $x\mapsto \frac{1}{(x-a)(x-b)}$ cannot be extended to a continuous function on the whole $[a,b]$.